# Elements not getting populated using Selenium C# with page scrolling in Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The website I'm trying to scrape is https://hitbtc.com/market-overview/overview.

I am trying to get cryptocurrency coin pairs from the page by accessing the following html (and other similar html for other coin pairs):

```
<div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__row ReactVirtualized__Row__odd ReactVirtualized__Table__row ReactVirtualized__Row__odd animation__redToWhite--2EMEW" role="row" style="height: 30px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 1202px; overflow: hidden; padding-right: 0px;">
    <div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn" role="gridcell" style="flex: 0 1 200px; overflow: hidden;">
        **<a href="/BTC-to-USDT" style="color: rgb(55, 71, 79); text-decoration: none;">BTC/USDT</a>**
    </div>
    <div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn" role="gridcell" style="flex: 0 1 200px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div>
            <div class="styles__imgUp--1O8Kn"></div>
            1.92%
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn" role="gridcell" title="₮ 59 843 794" style="flex: 0 1 200px; overflow: hidden;">₮ 59 843 794</div>
    <div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn" role="gridcell" title="₮ 6780.73" style="flex: 0 1 200px; overflow: hidden;">₮ 6780.73</div>
    <div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn" role="gridcell" title="₮ 6486.82" style="flex: 0 1 200px; overflow: hidden;">₮ 6486.82</div>
    <div class="ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn" role="gridcell" title="₮ 6833.25" style="flex: 0 1 220px; overflow: hidden;">₮ 6833.25</div>
</div>
```

I want to get the text from the first  tag, which should give me "BTC/USDT".  I found that by using Selenium's Driver.FindElements() I would only get the first 29 elements (i.e. the ones that are displayed without doing any scrolling).  Because of this I tried implementing a do-while loop to scroll down the page, obtaining element lists and appending them to a master list until the previously obtained list is the same as the current list (bottom of the page reached).  Here is my code:

```
List<IWebElement> totalElemList = new List<IWebElement>();
List<IWebElement> elementList = new List<IWebElement>();
List<IWebElement> prevList = new List<IWebElement>();

do
{
    prevList.Clear();
    prevList.AddRange(elementList);
    totalElemList.AddRange(prevList);
    var infoList = RetryingFind(By.ClassName("ReactVirtualized__Table__row"));
    foreach (var element in infoList)
    {
        elementList.Add(element.FindElement(By.TagName("a")));
    }
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Browser.Driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elementList[elementList.Count - 1]);
}
while (prevList != elementList);
```

However, elementList is not getting populated with any elements for some reason.  I added the Thread.Sleep() trying different sleep times up to 10 sec but it didn't fix the issue.  Then the ExecuteScript() line fails because it's trying to access index -1 of elementList, since its Count is 0.

I'm having trouble understanding why I was able to populate the element list before with at least some of the elements on the page, but when I use the do-while loop I get nothing.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you try by this Xpath instead of class name - `.//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/div/div/div`

Comment: That gives me one element with a tag type of anchor and text="Start trading now"

Answer (score 0):

It should ideally work with scroll. Check if there is any job event being triggered when you scroll. If so, try to invoke that function from IJavaScripExecutor. That should also load you with your elements.